# Is there a cryptography algorithm for signing values with two keys and requiring both to verify it?

Tags: cryptography, signing

Is there an algorithm that lets me sign a value with two keys at the same time, and in turn requires both keys to verify the signature?

Ie.

1. Sign X with Key1 and Key2 at the same time
2. Verify X is signed by these two keys

Like a joint bank account - to do anything on this account, the bank will require signatures from the two persons that initially created the account together.

I wouldn't bring the value into question, but the goal would be the ability to verify X was signed by two specific parties.

Comment: Please check if this question has been asked on [crypto.se] before. If not, you can ask over there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question

Comment: More likely to get answered on Crypto StackExchange rather than here.